# HTML Inspect element showing html not visible in the source code

Tags: jquery, html

Think i am missing something here, i have just downloaded this jquery plugin
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/HTML-Table-Based-Column-Chart-Plugin-For-jQuery-graph-js/

When i inspect the element in chrome I am seeing HTML that is not visible in the source code. Mainly ul classes which i would like to change 'x-axis' 'y-axis' 'bars'.

Just wondered whats going on or if i am just going mad!

Thanks all

Comment: The plugin is generating elements after the page loads, so they will not appear in the source. They will appear in the Inspect Element pane because that updates on-the-fly as elements are modified.

Comment: Oh right i see, so i guess this is no way of editing these values at all then? All i was looking to change was the values on the y-axis ul class

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean by changing the values. Just about any element in the DOM is modifiable via JavaScript, and if you just mean styling, you can just overwrite them with CSS.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't very clear my fault, on the ul class 'y-axis' i just want to edit the values i.e 0, 25, 50, 75, 100. I have never delved into javascript before if thats the way i am going to have to edit these in the DOM

Comment: I'd assume the plugin would allow you to set your own values, but if you wanted to override, you can do something like `$('.y-axis li:nth-child(2)').find('span').html('x');` in JQuery. Replace the `child(2)` with `child(3)` and so on to target each number. See [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/xt3jr9a2/) for an example.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion, i will give that a go for sure. Im surprised you cant change these values directly through the html.

Comment: Most of these plugins are initialized when your page loads in jquery, by putting some sort of script like `$('#myChart').chart();`. This turns `myChart` into a chart. Inside the parentheses of `chart()` you can define options, like the Y-Axis, X-Axis, colors, etc... Again, this is just an example.

Comment: many thanks for your help with this, i will have a play around with jquery and use your examples to see if i can get it to work. Where abouts in the html would i need to put any script i write?

Comment: You'd include jquery in the head of your document. Then, within script tags, you would put the code above in your head as well. If you want it to happen when the page loads, you would wrap it in `$(document).ready (function () { CODE HERE });` good luck!